# How to target last of type

Tags: css

I want the last unordered list on the page to not have a bottom border. The problem is, if I do last-of-type or last-child it changes all of the unordered lists because they're the only one in each section. Simplified code:

```
<div>
<section>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</section>

<section>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</section>

<section>
    <ul>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I can't just use a class because it's for dynamic content, where the client will be adding/deleting sections. Is there a selector I can use? Here's a pic of what it looks like live: [image]

Comment: Why don't you add the border to the `section` instead?

Comment: Oh man, I was going to say because the border shouldn't go all the way to the edge, but then I realized I can use a margin to fix that. Solved!

Answer (score 6):

[`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)

```
div > section:last-of-type > ul { 
  border-bottom: 0 none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
}
```

[`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```
div > section:last-child > ul { 
  border-bottom: 0 none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
}
```

Do those [CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) work?

Answer (score 2):

According to your page scheme, this will work:

```
div section:not(:last-child) ul {
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
```

This matches any `ul` within *the not-last* `section` of the document.